# Remove Characters from Google Sheets up to @ sign

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, trim, array-formulas

I have a column of E-mail addresses in a Google Sheet and want to remove all of the domain names and '@' symbol and copy this to a new column. For example:

- Column-A
- test@test.com
- testb@gmail.com
- testc@yahoo.com

Copied and removing the domains to:

- Column-B
- test
- testb
- testc

Answer (score 1):

all you need is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A&"", "(.+)@")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My answer as per my understanding maybe I'm wrong so please follow if I'm right to understand.
use split to get this

[image]

Go to Data
Click on Split Text to Columns 
Pick Custom From Drop Down 
enter @ and you get your result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use this function on google App script:

```
function myFunction() {
// Your spreadsheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
//if you got only one sheet
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
// This is in the case that your sheet as a header, if not replace 2 by 1 and (sheet.getLastRow()-1) by sheet.getLastRow()
var valuesColumnA = sheet.getRange(2,1,(sheet.getLastRow()-1)).getValues();
//Just to have each value in the same array
var valuesColumnAMapped = valuesColumnA.map(function(r){return r[0]});

valuesColumnAMapped.forEach(function(value, index){
var split = value.split("@");
sheet.getRange((index+2),2).setValue(split[0]);
})
}
```